# Check if the device supports webP image format

Tags: android, android-image, webp

Is there any way to check if the device supports an image format (`webP` format specifically). According to android doc (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), webP is supported in 4.0+ devices. 
[image]

But some of the 4.0+ devices are not supporting webP yet. (for ex, Noxia XL- http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Nokia_X_known_issues).
Is there any way to programmatically check if the device supports webP image or not.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: put small(1x1) webp into assets and try to decode it... if result is null or method throws an exception webp is not supported

Comment: @Selvin Thanks I will try this. But is there any straightforward way to achieve this? I mean does android provide any inbuilt function/api to check media compatibility?

Comment: *But is there any straightforward way to achieve this?* I'm not aware such way ... try: https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/d94b2b617519e0510a40

Comment: It's working. Thanks!. Can you post your comment as answer so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: ok, i did it ... better use new version ... i forgot to recycle Bitmap ... also Base64 is supported on API > 7 ... this version should work on all android ... and i did find smaller 1x1 webp image :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no API for this. So solution is to try to decode some webp image on device and check if it returns Bitmap.

This can be implemented like this:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class WebPUtils {
    //states
    private static final int NOT_INITIALIZED = -1;
    private static final int SUPPORTED = 1;
    private static final int NOT_SUPPORTED = 0;

    //why not boolean? we need more states for result caching
    private static int isWebPSupportedCache = NOT_INITIALIZED;

    public static boolean isWebPSupported() {
        // did we already try to check?
        if (isWebPSupportedCache == NOT_INITIALIZED) {
            //no - trying to decode
            //webp 1x1 transparent pixel with lossless
            final byte[] webp1x1 = new byte[]{
                    0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, 0x1A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x57, 0x45, 0x42, 0x50, 0x56, 0x50, 0x38, 0x4C,
                    0x0D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                    0x10, 0x07, 0x10, 0x11, 0x11, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0xFE,
                    0x07, 0x00
            };
            try {
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(webp1x1, 0, webp1x1.length);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    //webp supported
                    isWebPSupportedCache = SUPPORTED;
                    //don't forget to recycle!
                    bitmap.recycle();
                } else {
                    //bitmap is null = not supported
                    isWebPSupportedCache = NOT_SUPPORTED;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //we got some exception = not supported
                isWebPSupportedCache = NOT_SUPPORTED;
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return isWebPSupportedCache == SUPPORTED;
    }
}
```